# How can I check how many children does a node have?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the number of children that a node has but the only thing I can get is whether is has any children  not how many. For instance : 
I am using Xpath in C# (`XPathNodeIterator`, `XPathDocument` and `XPathNavigator`)

**EDIT:**

```
iterator.Count
```

is not what I want to achieve because it returns the number of all the nodes returned by the expression. I would like to know how many child nodes are there 'below' the `iterator.Current`

This is the Xml file I work with (as for an example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

`

My code:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(@"C:\\xmls\\chair1.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//*");

    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        stringList.Add(iterator.Current.Name);
        if(iterator.Current.HasChildren)   stringList.Add(iterator.Current.Value);
        stringList.Add(" ------- ");
    }
```

And what it produces

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
iterator.Current.SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.All).Count
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

```
XPathNodeIterator.Count
```

Should give you the Children Count, Or 0 in case no selected nodes.

Answer (score 2):

**A pure XPath solution -- use this XPath expression**:

```
count(//*)
```

**Or, the complete C# code** (seems to be the shortest of all offered so far :)

```
(int)navigator.Evaluate("count(//*)")
```

**Or, if you want to get the count of children of the *current* node, use**:

```
(int)iterator.Current.Evaluate("count(*)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this would show up the number of ALL the elements and I want the number of children under concrete element ( iterator ).

Comment: If you know the concrete node (element), evaluate this relative XPath expression against the current node: `count(*)` . I just saw that you are evaluating the expression `//*` and thought that you wanted to know the count of the selected elements.

Comment: @_Patryk: See my updated answer. This is the shortest expression from all presented answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = iterator.Count;
```

Play with reference! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx